# Execute remote script with local parameter value

Tags: ssh, scripting, scp, web

How can I automatize this task?

1) You are at A.
2) You ssh into B.
3) You run a script at B, that needs a parameter known at A.

First, I thought perhaps I could send the value when I opened the connection with ssh. Then, probably simpler, between 1) and 2), scp the entire script to the same location at B (replacing the old one). But still, how do I **execute** the script at B? (That is, how to automatize that last step. Of course, I could run it manually after ssh.)

Another thought, maybe discard of ssh altogether - I have a web page at B, so could the script somehow be invoked through an "under the hood" web interface?

Or would you do it in an altogether different way?

Comment: Also have a look at [Run if statement on remote machine](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40913/8979)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
myparameter=foobar
ssh user@server "myscript $myparameter"
```

This will execute `myscript foobar` on the server.

Comment: Simple as that! Works great. (I had to put a "./" before the script name because otherwise it looked for `~/.elm/aliases`.)

Comment: As a small warning, the use of double quotation marks (`"`) as opposed to single ones (`'`) is important here. Using double means that the shell on your local machine will expand the variable, then execute the `ssh` command. If single ones were to be used the local shell would not touch the command, which is sent on verbatim but is still be expanded in the remote shell.

Comment: Note that if `$myparameter` contains spaces, it will split on the server side. Bash's `printf` has a `%q` format that you could use. I have some example code, but it does not fit here. I'll create a new answer for it.

Comment: to me it does not work.

Answer (score 8):

(This is a follow-up to [my comment on the accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43140/execute-remote-script-with-local-parameter-value#comment59352_43141).)

Note that if `$myparameter` contains spaces, it will split on the server side. Bash's printf has a `%q` format that you could use. Example:

```
$ myparameter='hello; rm somefile'
$ ssh user@server "echo $myparameter"
hello
rm: cannot remove `somefile': No such file or directory

$ ssh user@server "echo $(printf '%q' "$myparameter")"
hello; rm somefile
```

Comment: if you want to forward `$@`, use `args=$(printf ' %q' "$@")`, then `ssh ... "$args"` (note a space prior `%q`).

Answer (score 1):

If it is safe to assume that `$myparameter` will **not** contain single quotes (otherwise see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115011/60283) or use the `printf '%q' ...` solution by janmoesen), you can just put single quotes around `$myparameter` to avoid the split-on-space problem on the server side.

```
myparameter="foo \" bar"
#myparameter="foo \" ' bar"

ssh localhost "set -xv; printf '%s\n' myscript '${myparameter}'"
ssh localhost "set -xv; echo $(set -xv; printf '%q' "$myparameter")"
```

Answer (score 1):

I hesitate to answer a 10-yo question, especially when there's already a perfectly good answer, but note that the 'remote' script doesn't actually *need* to be on B at all. This (a) makes the parameter substitution trivial, and (b) removes the complication of whether it's a good idea to have the script on the remote system at all (security issues/whatever).

The alternative is just to run ssh with [here doc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) input. In this case, the parameter substitution is done *locally*, and not on the remote system (as long as you don't quote the doc delimiter, in this case `EOF`):

```
portnum=1234
target=root@example.com
mydir=/var/www/bar
param=foo

ssh -p$portnum $target /bin/bash <<EOF
  set -e;
  cd $mydir;
  # create remote 3-character file '/var/www/bar/myfile' containing 'foo'
  echo -n $param > myfile
EOF
```