# Ping test a device in remote network

Tags: bash, ssh, networking

Trying here to perform some tests on a device in a remote network.

Already managed to do it using SSH between client and server, then ping command, but thought if there wasn't better way to do it.

`ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 -t email@addr.com "ping -i 1 -c 1 -W 1 192.168.12.115 > /tmp/ping.txt"`

Any sugestion?

Follows diagram of current situation.
[image: Current Diagram]

Comment: "Better" in what sense. Your current command leaves the `ping.txt` file on the server. Is that where you want it? If not, then just `ssh ... "ping ..." >/tmp/ping.txt` to save it on the client.

Comment: Somehow faster, don't know!

Would be SSH the most efficient way to keep pinging a device in a remote network every 5secs?

Isn't there a command that would do it more efficiently?

And yes, I'd prefer to keep the ping.txt file in the server for now!

Maybe later I'd remove it, don't know!

Comment: If you want to ping it efficiently every 5 seconds, you would not connect with `ssh` every five seconds, but connect (once) and then use `ping -i 5 -c 0` (or without the `-c` option, depending on what `ping` implementation you are using).  I'm not posting this as a solution as I don't know whether it solves any problem.

Comment: I believe yes, it does solves the problem, if you're saying that it is currently the best way.

But is there no problem in keeping an active ssh connection between server/client?

Comment: The main goal is to get this script running:

`#!/bin/bash

 ssh -v -o ConnectTimeout=10 -t user@serv.com

 while true; do

 date > /tmp/sdown.txt ;

 ping -i 1 -c 1 -W 1 192.168.12.116 ;

 sleep 1 ;

 if

 grep -q "64 bytes" ;

 then

:


 else

 mutt -s "Device Down!" email@account.com < /tmp/sdown.txt ;

 sleep 10 ;

 fi

 done`

But in the server I'm getting "Network Unreachable" from ping reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just managed to do it.

Main problem was Ssh syntax and missing Bash commands, as standard output redirection.

Another flaw was lack of `touch` command to previously create text file.

Follows current situation:

`ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 -t user@sshserver.com ' ping -i 5 -c 1 -W 5 192.168.33.23 2> /dev/null | grep "ttl=64" || touch /tmp/servdown.txt ; date > /tmp/servdown.txt ; mutt -s "Device Down!!!" email@address.com < /tmp/servdown.txt '`

Just found this answer too:

[Run if statement on remote machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40910/run-if-statement-on-remote-machine)